# How to disable JXTable default search action?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable, approximate-nn-searching

I have a `JXTable` in my swing app. When I press ctrl+F on the table, default search panel is opening.

[image]

This panel finds only substrings. I need to find similar words with my InputText. For example, I write "test" result may be "tost", "tests", "est", "tst" and etc.
How do i change this searching method to my own algorithm ? Is it possible ? Or Should I disable default seaching and create my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `JXTable#getSearchable` method and return your own custom `Searchable` implementation.

Note that the default implementation always returns the same instance (lazily created):

```
public Searchable getSearchable() {
    if (searchable == null) {
        searchable = new TableSearchable(this);
    }
    return searchable;
}
```

You might want to keep this in mind when overriding the method. I have no idea what the effect would be to always return a new instance.